# Are compile time checks possible for value parameters in C99 or GCC/Clang?

Tags: gcc, clang, c99

I have a function that takes a length value that must be no greater than 32,768. I want to check this condition at compile time because in an embedded system there is no good way to handle this fault. Furthermore the length value passed in should always be a compile time constant, typically `sizeof()`.

Is this possible in C99 or with GCC/Clang extensions?

Something like this, which obviously does not compile because `len` is not an integral constant.

```
#include <assert.h>
void fucntion(const uint16_t len)
{
    _Static_assert(len <= 32768, "length parameter too large");
}
```

Obviously making `len` const here does not have the desired effect and `_Static_assert` complains that len is not an integral constant.

I have considered using a macro to replace `func()` and then call it, but this has two significant downsides. Macro definitions do not support things like types or return values, i.e. you can't do

```
#define bool func(uint16_t len, const void *buffer)
```

As Nate Eldredge points out there is a GCC (and Clang) [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) that lets you at return a parameter.

Comment: Use a macro and check the length on call side. `integral constant` -> it's "integer" as in "integer constant expression".

Comment: @KamilCuk I was just adding a note about the macro option. And it is "integral constant", that's the term used for things that the compiler can compute at compile time and they are required for the _Static_assert macro. It doesn't have to be an integer, it could be any type.

Comment: I don't quite understand the objection to macros.  If your macro expansion includes a call to the real function, you get all the same benefits.  E.g. `#define func(l, b) { _Static_assert(l <= 32678,...); actual_function(l,b); }`

Comment: @NateEldredge it will work but most IDEs won't be able to do proper hinting or pre-compilation checks. It's not the end of the world but it would be nice if there was a better option. Sadly I don't think there is.

Comment: @NateEldredge actually the other issue with macros is lack of a return value.

Comment: @user11567957: You can work around that with [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), an extension supported by both gcc and clang.  `#define func(l, b) ({ _Static_assert(l <= 32678,...); actual_function(l,b); })`

Comment: @NateEldredge you are right, thanks.

Comment: `it is "integral constant"` No, no, I am going to be stubborn! [C11 6.7.10p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.10p3) "The constant expression shall be an integer constant expression". There is no such thing as "integral constant".

Comment: @KamilCuk The specific error that Clang gives me is "not an integral constant". I think maybe your link is referring to the parameter, i.e. if you put an expression in there it must evaluate to an integer. In my case it was complaining that part of the expression was not a compile time constant, integer or otherwise. It does work with floats, e.g. `(len>0.5)` produces an integer result (0 or 1).

Answer (score 1):

You can write static assertion using the old trick with `sizeof` and negative array and have a macro expand on call side:

```
void function_real(const uint16_t len);

#define function(len) ((void)sizeof(char[len > 32768 ? -1 : 1]), function_real(len))
```

In case you use C with variable length arrays, `sizeof` of an array will work with expression that aren't integer constant expressions. You can force `len` to be integer constant expression using the old bitfield trick for a static assertion. So similar, but better:

```
 #define function(len) ((void)sizeof(struct{ int a:len > 32768 ? -1 : 1;}), function_real(len))
```

You can do it like [`glibc`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/bits/string_fortified.h#L81) does with `­_FORTIFY_SOURCE` and use compile optimization with gnu builtins and enabled optimization:

```
void function_real(const uint16_t len);

static inline 
void function(const uint16_t len) {
     if (!__builtin_constant_p(len)) {
            extern __attribute__(( __error__ ( "Och no! len couldn't be evaulated at runtime" ) ))
            void compile_time_error(void);
            compile_time_error();
     } else if (len > 32768) {
            extern __attribute__(( __error__ ( "Och no! len is too small!" ) ))
            void compile_time_error2(void);
            compile_time_error2();
     }

     function_real(len);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, noting some small issues, is:

```
#define func(len, buffer)                                           \
({                                                                  \
    _Static_assert(len < 32768, "Length exceeds size of EEPROM");   \
    _func(len, buffer);                                             \
})


bool _func(uint16_t len, const void *buffer)
{ }
```

With thanks to Nate Eldredge.

The down side of this technique is that the IDE will only show information about the macro when browsing the code, so for example you won't get hints about the parameter types. You will still get the usual checks and errors at compile time though.